# How can get an animation duration in stingray?

Tags: lua, autodesk-stingray

Any level flow or lua script can get the object of animation in stingray?
I try to use "set_local_position()", but it still not work.

Below have the code in project.lua

```
function Project.on_level_load_pre_flow()
    setObjPostion(Project.level_names.testLv,"mainobj",stingray.Vector3( 100, 100, 100 ))
end


function setObjPostion(levelsString,newObjString,newPosition)
    world = stingray.Application.new_world()
    world:load_level(levelsString)
    myobj = stingray.World.unit_by_name(world,newObjString)
    --local newPosition2= stingray.Vector3( 100, 100, 1 )
    stingray.Unit.set_local_position(myobj,1,newPosition)
end
```

Comment: not related to your question, but is there any reason for world and myobj to not be local?

"but it still not work" is no problem description btw. it says nothing. Provide more information.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What are you trying to do?